# Interpret the CPU usage in SQL trace file

Tags: sql-server

During our performance evaluation, we run one load simulation with SQL trace on. And while analyzing the trace file I want to calculate the CPU usage. How to do it? (Please refer the screenshot attached)

[image]

So for the physical read, we observed a CPU spike but don't know how to interpret it.

Tha value showing for 53,682,888 reads, the CPU utilized is 1,254,911. Is it in a microsecond or in cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are represented in terms of time. This value could either be in millisecond or microsecond. For CPU - it would be number of milliseconds used by this particular process.

[This](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/) has been explained by Mr. Brad McGehee in a very detailed way with examples.

**CPU**

> This data column shows the amount of CPU time used by an event (in
>   milliseconds). Obviously, the smaller this number, the fewer CPU
>   resources were used for the query. Note that CPU data column is only
>   captured for the RPC:Completed, SP:StmtCompleted, and the
>   SQL:BatchCompleted events.

**Reads**

> This data column shows the number of logical page reads that occurred
>   during an event. Again, the smaller this number, the fewer disk I/O
>   resources were used for the event. Note that Reads are only captured
>   for the RPC:Completed, SP:StmtCompleted and the SQL:BatchCompleted
>   events.

**Writes**

> This data column shows the number of physical writes that occurred
>   during an event and provides an indication of the I/O resources that
>   were used for an event. Again, Writes is only captured for the
>   RPC:Completed,  SP:StmtCompleted and the SQL:BatchCompleted events.

Please find the below notes from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/view-and-analyze-traces-with-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) on this:

**Note**

*The server reports the duration of an event in microseconds (10^-6 seconds) and the amount of CPU time used by the event in milliseconds (10^-3 seconds). The SQL Server Profiler graphical user interface displays the Duration column in milliseconds by default, but when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, the Duration column value is written in microseconds.*

Same can be summarized [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3504/sql-server-profiler-data-columns-explained/):

[image: Columns with Descriptions]

I hope above helps.